# Create bindings to native libraries .net Maui

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, maui, .net-maui

Is there any way to bind native libraries like in Xamarin?
I have tried to do some native implementations in the new .NET Maui and haven't had success on it. I would really appreciate if someone has some information about it.

Comment: The dotnet team released a video on this a few days ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oibfI-ZsmzQ

Answer (score 5):

Yes, native library bindings are done the same way as in Xamarin, there are two new project templates "Android Java Library Binding" and "iOS Binding Library" just add them and follow regular Xamarin documentation in order to configure it:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

For android you can also check this git repo -  https://github.com/Bohdandn/MAUI.WebRTC.Demo,
unfortunately iOS doesn't compile there.

Comment: Thanks Bohdan, for this and your Github webrtc repo. I have a XF sln to upgrade. I'm hearing on the grapevine from senior iOS Maui devs, and online (e.g. here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1061273/how-to-create-an-ios-binding-library-for-net-maui) that binding libraries for iOS in particular do not work out of the box for Maui using these Xamarin methods. Can anyone point to Maui specific documentation for binding either iOS or Android? I found this video at least https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/dotnetconf-focus-on-maui/binding-native-libraries-for-dotnet-maui

Comment: It seems that they still haven't added MAUI specific docs for native bindings.
Regard compilation issues - you can track this issue: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/16001, problem is in transferring libraries between windows and mac build host, directly on mac everything works.

Answer (score 0):

For android jar files, I'm using **.NET MAUI class library**
[image]

```
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android'))">
    <EmbeddedJar Include="classes.jar" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Add this "ItemGroup" to your project, if you can create a wrap class like

[image]