# Matrix Calculations on GPU of mobile device from .NET MAUI Program

Tags: gpu, maui

Is there a way to calculate things like matrix calculations within a .NET MAUI App on the GPU? Question is if I could get some performance benefits if it is possible.

The .NET MAUI App should run on iOS and Android devices

Comment: That wouldn't be a cross-platform feature. If it can be done at all, it would be by writing a native library, in each device's native language, then [Create bindings to native libraries .net Maui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71787585/199364). [OPINION] I would periodically check to see what people are doing on mobile devices for gpu calculations, and wait for Maui's support for binding to native libraries to improve. Its not something I would recommend attempting yet, unless you are an expert on gpus or native mobile development.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Will you get some performance benefits, depends what you are doing.

Comment: As discussed in another thread, I am calculating a MIP with a Branch-and-Bound. There, I have a lot of Simplex calculations on the way with a lot of nodes that have to be calculated. On my PC it is calculated with 2-4 ms for one of my examples, but depending on how I did the node selections, it could take 10-20 seconds, for an easy example. Obviously, compared to a PC mobile devices are extremely less performant. As there are Games on mobile devices with usually lots of calculations, I thought, it could help to do my calculations on the GPU?

Comment: @OXO Try RenderScript.